# "Secure" setting is preventing cookie from being set

Tags: cookies, samesite

I am fairly new to cookies and had been tasked with figuring out why a cookie warning kept popping up even after the user clicked accept. It turned out that the cookie wasn't being set in some browsers (mostly Webkit, but also one time in Firefox).

After some exploring I discovered that by removing the setting "Secure" in the cookie string I could make it work as intended, but I don't have enough understanding of cookies to determine why that would prevent the cookie from being set in the first place. Can anyone explain?

This is my cookie for reference:

```
acceptCookies() {
        let expiry = new Date();
        let months = 1;
        let d = expiry.getDate();
        expiry.setMonth( expiry.getMonth() + months );
        if ( expiry.getDate() !== d ) {
            expiry.setDate( 0 );
        }

        document.cookie = 'acceptsCookies=1 expires=' + expiry.toUTCString() + '; SameSite=lax; Secure';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: It turned out that the cookie was being set on https, but not on http, which makes sense since the "Secure" setting only allows it to be sent over HTTPS.

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies